# Exchange 2013 running on 2012R2 changes time to about 5 hours ahead for a short time

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

I have an Exchange 2013 Server running Cu11 on 2012R2 OS. Twice now, it has randomly changed its system time, to about 5 hours ahead for a duration of about a couple minutes, then changed back to correct time. This freaks out the transport services and requires them to be restarted. After the services are restarted, time stamps on the messages are all the same time. the only way I've found to get the time stamp to sync is to move the affected user to another database.

Logs show that Updates were downloaded just before this happens, but doesn't show that anything installed...

Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks,
Travis

Answer (score 3):

Find out what the source of your time server is
from an elevated powershell ....shell

```
w32tm /query /computer:localhost /source
```

make sure you timezone is correct - your NTP server might jump ahead 5 hours because your local settings might be the wrong zone

from Powershell

```
[System.TimeZone]::CurrentTimeZone
```

at least knowing those two variables might point you in the right direction.

hope that helps.

Comment: I sure hope there aren't any NTP implementations that use/affected by time zones.

Comment: I forgot to add, the exchange server is set to one of our DCs, which is our NTP. That is synced with time.windows.com. Teh DC does not display the same symptoms.

Comment: time.windows.com is about the most unreliable time source I know. Set it to use pool.ntp.org - check their web site for the address for your location. 

Is this a virtual machine by any chance? I have seen this happen loads of times with VMs.

Comment: Greg - there aren't don't worry - but you know, if you want you computer to display the right time it's helpful to configure this.

Comment: Its not a VM. I've also seen VMs do funky time things.

Comment: @Sembee I don't think its the time server, if it was then I would have seen the time change on the DC as well, in the Event Log.

Comment: they sync from the hypervisor

Comment: @Rob-d, yep but its not a VM so there is no HV.

Comment: Is there anything logged at all to indicate a cause? It isn't something I have heard of. Are you in one of those locations that keeps changing their time zone configuration? (Although a five hour change is a bit much).

Comment: Nothing that tells me what cause the time change, just "The system time has changed" I'm in Eastern Time and we haven't changed zones as far as I can remember. We do daylight savings, but thats only an hour and happend a month or so ago. It seems to change to zulu/GMT when it happens.

Comment: you should do a malware scan - another thing that can change the time is the system battery (CMOS), but this is very unlikely to drop only a few hours, it would drop all the way back to the BIOS birthday - like 2002 or something ;-)